# Add complex formulas to a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formula that I don't want in my workbook until other specific functions are performed. So I'd like to have some VBA code that populates a column when I determine best. Here is the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'"& Day(C2)&"'!$A$127:$C$153"),3,TRUE)
```

The single ticks, and `&`s and `!`, always get hung up in the VBA code.

Is there some way to encapsulate a formula so it can be used in a range, or is that not available?

Do I need to encapsulate the various pieces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to double up any quotation marks:

```
Range("G2:G1000").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT(""'""& Day(C2)&""'!$A$127:$C$153""),3,TRUE)"
```

for example.

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid.... ;-) I thought I tried that several different times and ways.. worked like a champ...Thanks for the help.